# How to iterate a row and compare with each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

For example, if the name 'Mark' is repeated and if the 'Age' value or 'Gender' value is different when compared to other rows which contain 'Mark', then such columns must be removed.

Code for creating dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'John', 'Sunny', 'Sunny'], 
                  'Age' : ['22', '22', '25', '25', '17', '20', '20', '17', '23', '23'],
                  'Gender' : ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M']})
```

The dataframe is below:

```
       Name   Age   Gender
0      Mark   22    F
1      Mark   22    F
2      Mark   25    F
3      Mark   25    F
4      Mark   17    F
5      Nick   20    F
6      Nick   20    F
7      John   17    M
8      Sunny  23    M
9      Sunny  23    M
```

The expected output is:

```
       Name   Age   Gender
0      Nick   20    F
1      Nick   20    F
2      John   17    M
3      Sunny  23    M
4      Sunny  23    M
```

**For example in the 1st and 2nd rows Name is Mark and Age is 22 and Gender is F. Whereas in 3rd-row Name is Mark, Age is 25 and Gender is F, we can see Age has multiple values, then we have to remove rows which contains Mark**

Comment: What trouble are you having doing this yourself? This isn't really a programming issue

Comment: I disagree, @Laif.  This can be done in `pandas` using grouping and uniquing, but it's not obvious.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's entirely possible, I'm saying the question seems to concern a mathematical method or tool to perform the operations and not an issue OP is having with their program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner answer:

```py
df[df.Name.isin((s:=df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Name']).size().eq(1)).index[s])]
```

results in:

```py
    Name Age Gender
5   Nick  20      F
6   Nick  20      F
7   John  17      M
8  Sunny  23      M
9  Sunny  23      M
```

---

Perhaps worth noting: the walrus-operator does still allocate memory for a variable `s` that Python's garbage-collector will *eventually* de-allocate. If you would need a `Series` representing whether any `Name` has different rows, as in below, then it'd be worth explicitly assigning it.

```py
>>> s
Name
John      True
Mark     False
Nick      True
Sunny     True
dtype: bool
```

anywhere else in your calculations, it's likely worth explicitly assigning it to a variable to which you maintain a reference.

---

Explanation:

```py
# from the OG df
df[
   # boolean mask if the name is in
   df.Name.isin(
                # walrus-operator to temporarily hold result
                # drop the duplicate rows (duplicates name + age + gender)
                (s:=df.drop_duplicates()
                       # group on Name
                       .groupby(['Name'])
                       # after dropping duplicates, there's only one record
                       # i.e. no different age/gender records for same name
                       .size().eq(1))
                # mask on names where no-duplicates is true, drop names where false
                ).index[s]
               # pass as series to `df.Name.isin`
               )
  ]
```

Comment: When i tried to run this code df[df.Name.isin(s:=(df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Name']).size().eq(1)).index[s])], its returning an error like name 's' is not defined

Comment: @NithinReddy what version of Python are you using? The walrus operator (`s:=...`) is [new as of Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

Comment: I'm using python 3.8.5,  but its returning 's' is not defined

Comment: Is there any alternative?

Comment: @NithinReddy fixed; had a `(` in the wrong spot.

Comment: Thank you!! It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is tricky, so I'll explain each line.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'John', 'Sunny', 'Sunny'], 
                  'Age' : ['22', '22', '25', '25', '17', '20', '20', '17', '23', '23'],
                  'Gender' : ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M']})

print(df)

# First, drop all the rows that are exact duplicates of each other.

df1 = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df1)

# If any rows that remain have a duplicate name, those need to go.

df2 = df1.duplicated('Name')
print(df2)

# Go build a DF with just the names that were duplicated.

df3 = df1[df2]['Name']
print(df3)

# Find all the rows in the original df that have a name in this list,
# invert that set, and the result is what we want.

df4 = df[~df.Name.isin(df3)]
print(df4)
```

Several of those operations can be combined to make a one-liner, but I think this makes it more clear.  I've added blank lines to separate the dataframes in the output.

Output:

```
    Name Age Gender
0   Mark  22      F
1   Mark  22      F
2   Mark  25      F
3   Mark  25      F
4   Mark  17      F
5   Nick  20      F
6   Nick  20      F
7   John  17      M
8  Sunny  23      M
9  Sunny  23      M

    Name Age Gender
0   Mark  22      F
2   Mark  25      F
4   Mark  17      F
5   Nick  20      F
7   John  17      M
8  Sunny  23      M

0    False
2     True
4     True
5    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool

2    Mark
4    Mark
Name: Name, dtype: object

    Name Age Gender
5   Nick  20      F
6   Nick  20      F
7   John  17      M
8  Sunny  23      M
9  Sunny  23      M
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim!! It is working.